# Step definition and implementation

Tags: java

In the main program logic (not in tests), I would like to have separate execution steps defined in plain text, while the corresponding code handles the implementation of each instruction (similar to "Behavior Driven Development").

Something like, having a file with:

```
Process file input.txt
Send the details to the customer by email
Update the customer details in the database
Update the change log
```

To be associated with an implementation.

I am missing two things:

1. What is this way of "step definition and implementation" called? Since whenever I search, I find libraries meant to be used for testing.
2. Any hints about libraries that can do the automatic mapping between the step and the implementation?

Comment: I'd call this a stripped down version of BDD. Or pseudo-code.

Comment: Seems like you need to create a DSL (domain-specific language), or maybe just the command pattern (if that's what it's called).

Comment: So you want an interpreter for some custome script langauge which the end-user can use to interact with the program? Or do _you_ want to define execution sequences for your program in this script language? I ask this because I don't see a great benefit in doing it for the second reason. IMHO it would just be more error prone then linking some java methode calls together.

Comment: @Ackdari: I wand to define my own steps. The reason it is not done with the code, because I would have thousands of steps, and putting them outside the code, would make the logic more or less "configurable", and easy to understand by non-technical members.

Comment: @AhmedAshour but again to do see the benefit. The code can be configurable if you have a good java-api to talk to. Also doing it that way would definitly decrease the performance. The JVM on its own can at times be painfully slow and you want to put snother interpretion of instructions on top of that? I don't consider this a good plan. I would recomend that you design a good API which you then could use in a static method or something like that to define your execution sequence. Also this kind of scripting would be really hard to debug.